# Python data attributes can be used by client

Tags: python

I was going through [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks) and couldn't understand the line:

> Data attributes may be referenced by methods as well as by ordinary
>   users (“clients”) of an object  In other words, classes are not usable
>   to implement pure abstract data types. In fact, nothing in Python
>   makes it possible to enforce data hiding — it is all based upon
>   convention. (On the other hand, the Python implementation, written in
>   C, can completely hide implementation details and control access to an
>   object if necessary; this can be used by extensions to Python written
>   in C.)

Comment: _nothing in Python makes it possible to enforce data hiding — it is all based upon convention_ Yes, that's how it is.  What other help do you need?

Comment: It's unclear what your question is - what *do* you understand from that quote, and what specifically has confused you?

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between Python in general and the C Python implementation specifically?